# Extracting elements from a data.frame object in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For each country ("BR", "MX", "RU"), I would like to create a data.frame object containing three columns: @INDICATOR, @TIME_PERIOD, and @OBS_VALUE.

```
library(IMFData)

IRFCL.available.codes <- DataStructureMethod("IRFCL")
names(IRFCL.available.codes)
indicators_IRFCL <- IRFCL.available.codes[[3]]

databaseID <- "IRFCL"
startdate = "2006-01-01"
enddate = " "
checkquery = FALSE

queryfilter <- list(CL_FREQ = "Q", CL_AREA_IRFCL = c("BR", "MX", "RU"), CL_INDICATOR_IRFCL = "", CL_SECTOR_IRFCL = "")
RESERVES <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, checkquery)
```

Inside `RESERVES`, one can find @INDICATOR and Obs (which contains @TIME_PERIOD and @OBS_VALUE for each @INDICATOR).

Comment: just put `tidy = T` inside `CompactDataMethod()` and you'll get a data.frame.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot. Now I just need to ```dplyr::filter```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(IMFData)
library(dplyr)

RESERVES <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, checkquery, tidy = T)
```

and then

```
RESERVES %>%
  select(`@REF_AREA`, `@TIME_PERIOD`, `@INDICATOR`, `@OBS_VALUE`) %>%
  group_by(`@REF_AREA`) %>%
  group_split(keep = F) -> list_of_tibbles
```

This way you get a list of data.frames (tibbles)

Comment: Is it possible to have a common column ````@TIME_PERIOD```` for all indicators (one column for each ````@INDICATOR````)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this might be material for another question.

Comment: ```BRLRES <- as.data.frame(list_of_tibbles[[1]])
colnames(BRLRES) <- c("Date", "Indicator", "Data")

BRLRES <- reshape(BRLRES, timevar="Indicator",idvar="Date",direction="wide")```

Comment: `reshape()` is beautiful